# Understanding PMTK order

Tags: nmea

I am a high school student trying to decode a pycom code I was given, and within it I found this:

> $PMTK001,353,3,1,1,1,1,0'
>   I have been searching a lot about this online, and I know that for PMTK001
>
> 0 = Invalid command / packet.
>
> 1 = Unsupported command / packet type
>
> 2 = Valid command / packet, but action failed
>
> 3 = Valid command / packet, and action succeeded

while for PMTK353,

> ‘0’: disable (DO NOT search GPS satellites)
>
> ‘1’ or non-Zero: search GPS satellites

Unfortunately, I've tried to put these messages together, but they don't seem to make much sense to me as of now. Could someone help me understand what the "3,1,1,1,1,0'" part says?